# Adding CentOS 6.8 Client to Spacewalk

Tags: installation, python, yum, packages, spacewalk

I'm trying to add a **CentOS 6.8** client to **Spacewalk 2.6** to I can push out updates. In order to add the client I need to first install some packages: **rhn-client-tools rhn-check rhn-setup rhnsd m2crypto yum-rhn-plugin rhncfg-actions**.

When I try to install them with yum I get the following errors:

Error: Package: rhnlib-2.6.3-1.el7.noarch (spacewalk-client)
**Requires: python(abi) = 2.7**

I read that **CentOS 6 requires python 2.6.6** and upgrading it will break yum. I tried installing python 2.7 but if I run 'python' it still points to 2.6.6. I tried adding an alias in /.bashrc and pointed to the python2.7. I tried to install again but it says that 2.6.6 is installed and I need 2.7.

I feel like there has to be a workaround for this. If there's a way to install the packages on a way to add the client without needing the packages I would greatly appreciate the help/assistance.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to install packages from the spacewalk-client repository for CentOS 7 on CentOS 6. This has no chance of working. Install the correct packages instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help, that was the issue. Only problem I'm running into now is 'python-hwdata' is a dependency for the packages listed above but I can't find it when I search with yum.